# mac excel 2011 mangling "nestlé" when importing text file

Tags: macos, excel, unicode, utf-8

If I have a text file consisting solely the word "NESTLÉ", how do I open this in Excel without mangling the accent?

This question isn't quite covered by other questions on the site, so far as I can tell.  I don't see any difference in any import option.  I try to tell Excel it's UTF-8 when I import it, and the best that happens is that the É => _.

If I create a Google Docs spreadsheet with just that word and save it out to Excel format, then open in Excel, I get the data un-mangled, so that's good, it's *possible* to represent the data.

I've never seen Excel 2011 do anything smart with a UTF8 BOM indicator at the start of a file.

Does anyone else have different experience there, or know how to get this data from a text file to Excel without any intermediate translation tools?

Comment: What encoding is the text file?  *Is* it UTF-8?

Comment: @MarkTolonen: As near as I can tell, yes.  I can create a new plaintext file in TextEdit, save it, and on the save dialog, it says "Plain Text Encoding: Unicode (UTF-8)".  Can it be more straight-forward than that?  If you have suggestions for other tools (for ex., Emacs or TextWrangler) I'm happy to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

I saved a file with that word in multiple formats.  The results when opened with Excel 2010 by simply dragging and dropping the appropriate .txt file on it:

**Correct**

> ANSI<sup>1</sup> (Windows-1252 encoding on my system, which is US Windows)
>   UTF-8 with BOM
>   UTF-16BE without BOM
>   UTF-16LE without BOM
>   UTF-16LE with BOM

**Incorrect**

> UTF-8 without BOM (result NESTLÃ‰)
>   UTF-16BE with BOM (result þÿNESTLÉ)

Do you know the encoding of your text file?  Interesting the UTF-16BE *with* BOM failed.  Excel is probably using a heuristic function such as [IsTextUnicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318672%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

<sup>1</sup>The so-called ANSI mode on Windows is a locale-specific encoding.

Comment: Hi Mark, responding to you here too.  My default mangling is: "NESTLÃ‰".  Trying Word instead of the default Apple editor...  no. My list of export options is poor impoverished compared to yours, but I see UTF-8 with BOM coming into Excel as "ï»¿NESTLÃ‰", and if I explicitly say to import it with UTF-8, I just get "__NESTL_" instead.  (Ignore italics, those are just more underlines.) Word gives me no UTF-16, or Windows-1252 options.

Comment: I should clarify I'm on Windows, not a Mac, so it is probably an implementation issue between Excel versions.  The encoding  your are getting is latin1 or a variant (Windows-1252, ISO-8859-1), so if you can save in that format it should work.

Comment: Don't worry, I could tell you were on Windows.  I thought I'd tried every possible combination, but saving from Word in "Western (Latin-1)" and then opening it in Excel in "Windows (ANSI)" did work!  That's  a start.  Emacs give the interesting mode line of "uu1(DOS)", which appears to be ISO-8859-1 with DOS line endings.  The line endings don't appear to matter; if I use Emacs to convert my original file from UTF-8 to Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1, then Excel does open it properly.  That's ... getting better!